# Need help understanding the use of the error function $(\operatorname{erf})$ in a text

Tags: calculus, error-function

I'm reading [this text](http://www.arbylon.net/publications/ilda.pdf) and there is a simple toy example on page 3:

$$H(S_1), H(S_2), H(S_3) \sim \operatorname{Dir}(\alpha \operatorname{erf}(-1), \alpha(\operatorname{erf}(1)-\operatorname{erf}(-1)), \alpha(1 - \operatorname{erf}(1)))$$

The Dirichlet distribution takes positive arguments but $\operatorname{erf}(-1)$ is a negative number and is thus not a valid parameter.

I assume $\operatorname{erf}$ is the error function as described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)

Did I misinterpret the meaning of $\operatorname{erf}$?

Comment: FYI, to typeset $\operatorname{erf}$ use `\operatorname{erf}` rather than `erf`.

Comment: This is curious indeed. I would contact the author if possible.